# XMLWorkerHelper does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments in c#

Tags: c#, xmlworker

[image]i am trying to pdf generate using html template in mvc4
and i have adding xmlworker packages and write a following code.
i will build my solution then show in following error.
XMLWorkerHelper does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments
Please suggest me... 
Controller:-

```
 public void abcd()
            {
                try
                {
                    string UniqueNumber = Request.QueryString["UniqueNumber"];
                    string strFileName = UniqueNumber;
                    string strFileExtension = ".pdf";
                    string strContentType = FileManager.FileContentType_application_pdf;
                    string strExportData = string.Empty;
                    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 43f, 50f, 5f, 50f);
                    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
                    var output = new MemoryStream();
                    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                    XMLWorkerHelper htw = new XMLWorkerHelper();
                    StringReader sr;
                    sr = new StringReader(Convert.ToString(ExportData.UserDetails(UniqueNumber)));
                    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, output);
                    pdfDoc.Open();
                    htmlparser.Parse(sr);
                    pdfDoc.Close();
                    strFileName = strFileName.Replace(" - ", "-").Replace(" ", "-").Replace("--", "-");
                    Response.ClearContent();
                    Response.Buffer = true;
                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}{1}",                 strFileName, strFileExtension));
                    Response.ContentType = strContentType;
                    Response.Charset = "";
                    Response.BinaryWrite(output.ToArray());
                    Response.Flush();
                    Response.End();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //

                }
            }
```

Comment: `XMLWorkerHelper` doesn't have a constructor with 0 or 1 parameters. You should right click on it and `Go To Definition` to see what constructors it **does** have. And use that constructor (passing in the number of parameters that it expects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the Singleton pattern is used within this assembly Dip.

Please replace your current code, `XMLWorkerHelper htw = new XMLWorkerHelper();` with this `XMLWorkerHelper htw = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance();` and give it a shot.

As a side note, you may want to look into the [IDisposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=netframework-4.8) interface. Check if any of the objects your are "newing" up implement it and dispose of them.

Comment: but actual problem not resolved ...please check following link and let me know if any solution ...https://stackoverflow.com/q/58457407/8620388